# Unexpected Token s3 error on AWS Lambda Node 12.X

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using Node 12.x version to write my Lambda function. Here is the Parsing error that I am getting. What could be the reason?[image: Parsing Error: Unexpected Token S3]

**Update**

```
const im = require("imagemagick");
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");
const {promisify} = require("util");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const resizeAsync = promisify(im.resize)
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile)
const unlinkAsync = promisify(fs.unlink)


AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-south-1'})
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let filesProcessed = event.Records.map((record) => {
        let bucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
        let filename = record.s3.object.key;
    //Fetch filename from S3
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: filename
    };
    //let inputData = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
    let inputData = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    //Resize the file
    let tempFile = os.tmpdir() + '/' + uuidv4() + '.jpg';
    let resizeArgs = {
        srcData: inputData.Body,
        dstPath: tempFile,
        width: 150
    };
    await resizeAsync(resizeArgs)
    //Read the resized File
    let resizedData = await readFileAsync(tempFile)

    //Upload the resized file to S3
    let targetFilename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.') + '-small.jpg')
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket + '-dest',
        Key: targetFilename,
        Body: new Buffer(resizedData),
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }
    await s3.putObject(params).promise();
    return await unlinkAsync(tempFile)
})

await Promise.all(filesProcessed)
return "done"
```

}

Here is the same code. I am getting Unexpected token S3 error when hovering the red mark (shown in the image)

Comment: Are you sure about the question? I guess the return is not in the string format and hence the issue. Maybe get us some code instead of screenshot would help us understand better.

Comment: sure. I'll update with code

Comment: @rey updated. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, declare inputData as below and initialize it with the response from the getObject.

```
let inputData;    
var params = {
    Bucket: "examplebucket", 
    Key: "HappyFace.jpg"
};
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     inputData = data;           // successful response
});
```

For more, you can refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)

Comment: I don't see the error anymore but I am not getting any output as well. I put a console.log() inside if and else. And also one on the starting of the callback function. None of them is showing up on CloudWatch

Comment: Is the event coming in? Check the file name in the body of the event once. Try updating the above in a if loop if the filename exist.

Comment: I tried implementing the way you specified once again, and it worked. Thank you